# Can someone explain please what does this do : n&1?

Tags: c++

Here is the code, I know what does it do , but I don't understand, what does the if condition do?

```
if(n&1)
    {
        for(i=n/2,j=n/2+1;;i--,j++)
         if(__gcd(i,j)==1)
         {
            cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;
            break;
         }
    }
    else 
    {
        for(i=n/2-1,j=n/2+1;;i--,j++)
         if(__gcd(i,j)==1)
         {
            cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;
            break;
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know about bitwise operators?

Comment: Functionally identical to `if(n%2==1)`

Comment: Look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

Comment: i know only about AND, NO , OR operators , is it also one of them ?

Comment: @AndrianRotari It's bitwise AND.

Comment: Yes, this is bitwise AND.

Comment: and what is it meaning in this code, if it is the AND operator , what does this if check ?

Comment: and also , i know that you use AND operator , with two of this characters : & , can you use with only one or what ?

Comment: The condition checks if the zero bit is set. It's different from `&&`. Check [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) 1st please before asking such trivia next time.

Answer (score 5):

Its a bitwise operator. There's a search term for you!

The & operator provides a mask that "cancels out" bits in the first depending if they're set in the second parameter - so assume N is the number 17, that expressed in binary is 00010001, the number 1 in binary is 00000001, so masking the two together will "blank" the first set of bits, leaving you with N as 00000001.

Basically that particular if statement drops all except the last bit, which is either 0 or 1, so it is a condition detecting if N is odd or even.